# Why isn’t $U= [ 0,∞) ⊂ \Bbb R$ a subspace of $\Bbb R$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I’m prepping for my Linear Algebra course and I came across this question.

I know for something to be a subspace it must satisfy three properties:

1. it contains the 0 vector
2. it’s closed under scalar multiplication
3. it’s closed under addition

My best guess is that it’s not actually a vector? But an interval? But I’m pretty lost.

Comment: Well, there are some issues with satisfying condition 2.

Comment: Not a subspace, but is a [convex cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone)

Comment: note on intuition: Vector subspaces don't have much "variety". If it's dimension 1 it looks like a line. If it has dimension 2 it looks like a plane, etc. This is a ray not a line (since it doesn't extend in both directions) so it can't be a vector subspace. Now you just have to figure out what axiom it violates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of a subspace as a smaller vector space inside of your larger vector space. This means a subspace, like a vector space, will consist of vectors. In particular, the subspace will consist of some sub collection of vectors from your original vector space, in this case $\mathbb{R}$.

When trying to find a subspace, the first thing you should ask is "Is this a subset of vectors from my original vector space?". This is the "something" in your statement where you say "for something to be a subspace". What you could say is "For a subset of a vector space to be a subspace...".

In this case $U$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, not a vector, so it is a candidate to be a subspace. But then as you mention, you have to check those three properties.

They purposefully chose $U$ so that it would satisfy property $1$, it contains $0$.

It is also closed under addition (property 3). But as some others have mentioned, it does not satisfy property 2. To prove something is not a subspace, you should produce an explicit counter example to one of these properties. In this case if you chose $1 \in U$, what real number $r \in \mathbb R$ could you multiply it by so that $r \cdot 1 \not\in U$?

This will give you your counter example! A couple words on how to approach these types of problems generally:

I really like that in your last sentence you're trying to understand what type of object $U$ is. This is really important in math: answering the question "What kind of thing is this thing?" In this case, $U$ is a subset, which is exactly the type of object that could be a subspace. Once you check this, you then work through your definition of subspace. If you can verify every property, you're done, it's a subspace. But if there's one you can't quite verify, try to see if you can come up with a counterexample (like property 2 in this case!).

This stuff can get tricky, but really understanding definitions helps a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Saying that $U$ is closed under scalar multiplication means that is $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in U$, then $\lambda x\in U$. But this is clearly false: $-1\in\mathbb{R}$, $1\in U$, but $(-1)\times1=-1\notin U$.